# Can we mount a folder into docker such that it overwrites the sub-directories if present; retaining the rest from host?

Tags: mount, docker

I know we can mount a folder into a docker container like this:

`docker run -v /home/user:/home/user <image>`

But it will mask everything that is present in the container's `/home/user`.

Is it possible to mount in such a way that if the file or folder is present in host machine's `/home/user/`, it will be mounted; everything else will be retained from the container?

For example, suppose I have the following contents in my host and container respectively:

**Host**

```
/home/user/.ssh
/home/user/.config
/home/user/code-server  # v2
```

**Container**

```
/home/user/apps/web-server
/home/user/code-server  # v1
```

I would like to have a union of these after mounting:

```
/home/user/.ssh
/home/user/.config
/home/user/apps/web-server  # because the container has it.
/home/user/code-server  # because the host has it.
```

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: no. You'd need to either create an overlay filesystem outside of the container to mount as a volume (not using container folders), or more likely you want to store files inside the container in a different location and restore them on the container startup.

I've done the latter with the `save-volume` and `load-volume` scripts in [this base image](https://github.com/sudo-bmitch/docker-base#volume-caching) that you can use to implement this. You save off the volume to a directory during the build process (inside your Dockerfile). And then the entrypoint runs a load to restore files to the volume directory.

Comment: Thanks -  I will check those scripts! I was thinking of writing some logic in the entrypoint to do this if there are no other alternatives.